# Operation and time complexity in arbitrary array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Suppose you're given an arbitrary array of length n. Which of the following operations can you perform on the array in worst-case O(1) time?

A. Remove the *i*th element, decreasing the size by 1
B. Insert an element at *i*th position , increasing the size by 1
C. find the maximum element
D. Swap the elements at location *i* and *j*

In this question, I'm not sure about the definition of arbitrary array. It seems that D is correct, but I'm not sure. Could anybody explain it? Many thanks!

Comment: This looks like a homework question in which case you should ask your teacher what is meant by *"arbitrary array"*

Comment: [`arbitrary`](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/arbitrary): *subject to individual will or judgment without restriction; contingent solely upon one's discretion* --- So, *any* array regardless of type, size and actual values, except that you know size is `n`, but value is `n` is also arbitrary.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking for definition of English words are not a [*programing* or *software* problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think by arbitrary, it might just mean that the values of the array don't matter.

A) Removing the ith element and decreasing the array's size by one has an O(n) complexity: when removing an ith element, you have to move all the other elements down one index. If you removed the 0th element, you would need to move n - 1 elements down one index.

B) Inserting an element at the ith position and increasing the array's size by one has an O(n) complexity, for a similar reason. If I add an element to the beginning of the array, I need to move all the other elements up one. Not to mention that because arrays have fixed size, I would also need to create a new array and copy the former elements.

C) Finding the maximum element will at least take O(n) times. You need to look through each element to find the max value, right? Well, if the max value is at position n at the end of the array, you need to go through all the values up to that point.

D) Swapping elements is just O(1). It's a constant operation that doesn't require for or while loops or what not.

Something like that. Hope it helps!